# Implementation of various business logic for the same markup

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good day!
I'm working on a ASP.NET project refatoringom and faced such a problem, because the project is international, there are several of its locations and in many places on the business logic, specific actions are solved with the help of a not so sly inspection:

```cs
    if (IsChina) 
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (IsFrance)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Naturally such code quickly grows, it becomes unbearable and you can not support the re-use. As a result, when the problem appeared to change the layout for a particular location, it had to make to the code behind, what is even more terrible.
It turns out we have two problems:
A. Requires different markup to the same (similar) business logic
Two. Need the same layout with different business logic

If the first paragraph all just decided literate class hierarchy and inheritance, then the second problems, the most important of which is to duplicate the layout. So what is my question, can we somehow inherit the layout (without adding it to the code behind) or something with the help of a trick one ASCX file to bind several implementations of business logic, which in turn would be dynamically connected at the right time. Maybe someone with something similar has already experienced?

Thank you!

Comment: Separate your business logic into it's own separate hierarchy and out of the aspx.cs file, and have the single page invoke it to do the business work.

Answer (score 0):

The critical issue I see is to think very hard about the design of your solution.

In Markup (aspx or ascx):  What controls are common and what ones are variable? The common ones can be put on a MasterPageFile and referenced by your other markup files.

In Code-Behind(aspx.cs or ascx.cs):  Only put the logic here that directly relates to the controls on the page.

In Business Logic classes(.cs):  Again, the common elements (methods, properties, etc) should be put into "parent" files (base classes) while putting more unique elements in "child" classes which inherit from the base.